Regex to specficially capture word A only when when word B DOES NOT exist ANYWHERE in the string
UPDATE: I DO NOT WANT to select the entire string. I already figured out how to do that. In my exmaple I want the regex to only select "greatest thing". Thank you.
As the title states I want to use regex to capture a word ONLY when another word DOES NOT exist in a string
So if "greatest thing" is the "good word" and "cheese" is the bad word then all these cases should FAIL:
I love cheese, it's the greatest thing, I really need to buy more cheese today!
I love cheese, it's the greatest thing!
It's the greatest thing, I really need to buy more cheese today!
And only this case should succeed:
I love apples, they're the greatest thing, I really need to buy more apples today!
You'd think this is elementary Regex,. and maybe it is, but I tried using 2 AI programs (ChatGPT and Gemini) and both failed to come up with a code that would actually achieve this. It seems like it would get stuck on looking ahead AND behind for the "bad word" so it would work only if the "bad word" was either before or after the "good word" but never both.
Btw I'm using this with the addon FoxReplace. I want to find and replace a word, but only when it's not already there in the string, basically. Dunno if that's relevant or not.

ECMAscript supports negative lookaheads.
^(?!.*cheese)(.*)greatest thing(.*)$

See: https://regex101.com/r/wGpuyy/1

You may also be able to use an unanchored form, which will allow to match/replace more than a single instance of the pattern in the string:
(?<!cheese.*)greatest thing(?!.*cheese)

See: https://regex101.com/r/3jTaha/3

You didn't read my question thoroughly. I don't want the regex to select the entire string, I can get it to do that easily. I just want to select "greatest thing" (in the example). That's the part that's giving me trouble.

You said "I want to find and replace a word". The regex101 link shows an example of doing exactly that.
